# connecting internet TV modem to repeater router, will it work?

Tags: tv

I've internet TV at home, it works via special modem which connects to router via Lan interface.

I'd like to move Tv to a room which has no router. so i'd like to use wifi for internet TV.

My plan is this, buy another wifi router, set it to repeat sygnal of primary router and attach this TV modem to repeater router via Lan interface.

Will this work? I have limited understanding of how internet TV works, so I'm not sure if my strategy will work... does router have to have some special feature to allow this service? will my strategy work?

Answer (score 0):

A home network only needs a single router.

For extending the network, use [WiFi repeaters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_repeater) or [powerline ethernet (homeplug)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug)

An "Internet TV" is a TV that can use wired or wireless networking to access content from your PCs, from other local devices (e.g. NAS) and from Internet services. So far as the LAN is concerned it is just like any PC that needs access to local and Internet services.

In a typical home, having multiple routers is a recipe for confusion.